# Unable to test receipt validation in sandbox on Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, mac-app-store, receipt

I am going to upload to the Mac App Store my new app and wanted to test the receipt validation before. I followed this guide[enter link description here](https://www.objc.io/issues/17-security/receipt-validation/#configuring-test-users) and also the Apple one.

Building, exporting and installation runs fine. However when I try to start it from the Finder, nothing happens and I get the following message in the console:

```
Disallowing com.xxx.yyy because no eligible provisioning profiles found
```

What kind of profile it can be? Googling didn't give me any answer